# Ext JS 3.3 Edit multiple rows at once

Tags: javascript, extjs

We have some records populated using EditorGridPanel inside a TabPanel.

Currently records can be modified and saved one by one.
I am looking for best approach to provide an ability to edit multiple records at the same time.

Here is my approach and challenges.

-User selects multiple records

-A button provided to unhide a FormPanel with the fields to be modified. (This can be done in same tab OR a new tab can be opened )

-The user changes the needed elements and clicks Save.

-The changed elements are updated across all selected rows.

**Challenges:**

-I am using Ext JS 3.3.1 library.

-Not able to figure out how the data can be passed from the new form to records on first tab

-Tried creating one blank record on same grid. Updating it will make updates to all selected records.

Would be great if more thoughts/pointers can be shared.

**Sorry** I haven't provided more info codewise. However hoping that I have explained the problem. 
 I can provide more specific info as needed. An image would have been easier to describe however unable to attach

Comment: Why not use a single click row editor? This will result in fewer clicks to edit.

Comment: @DmitryB The problem is not with How many clicks to edit. Problem is with number of rows to edit. That's the main factor driving the requirement. Many a times there are same comments/ updates needed for more than one record. And we want to avoid the efforts by having to do it one time for each record.

Comment: Perhaps just use rowselectors and then popopen a modal window with a form to fill out. Once the form is submitted pickup the rows selected and send the ids to the server to update with values from the form?

Comment: Thanks @DmitryB... I had quit the model window approach for couple of reasons 1) Could not open the form window on click of button. existing coding seems to be little complex and not straightforward OR I am very novice to ext js 2) before submitting to actual server, I would need to populate main tab with the updated rows. So that user can do any adjustments. That means, once I open the form in modal window and do the updates, I would need to bring control to main tab which should be showing the updated records. Anyway,  I think I should focus on model form window and read more on it.